# C# syntax - class name with indexer?

Tags: c#

This is probably a stupid question, but here goes. I have this statement in my program:

```
 // No node should be shown as selected
 mdxTreeList.Selection.Set(new TreeListNode[0]);
```

The variable mdxTreeList is an instance of the DevExpress XtraTreeList.TreeList control, and TreeListNode is the name of another DevExpress class. But what exactly does the syntax "new TreeListNode[0]" mean? I would have thought it was a syntax error, but it works fine. (If I remember right, this statement originally came from a DevExpress sample program.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a one-dimensional array with zero length (i.e. zero members). The type is `TreeListNode[]`.

Some people prefer to write the same thing as `new TreeListNode[] { }` but that's just a matter of taste.

By the way, since [`static` indexers are not allowed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154489), there's no possibility this could be an indexer access. (Of course indexers are *meant* to "look like" arrays, so it is not by accident that both use square bracket `[]` syntax.)

Comment: Thanks for your extra comments. Brain glitch on my part, feeling very embarrassed. Only excuse I have is that I had just tried to create a new TreeListNode object with "new TreeListNode()", and that failed, saying the constructor was internal, and then I happened to notice this statement where "new" and "TreeListNode" were involved and ... oh dear, oh dear.

Answer (score 4):

That's just an array of type `TreeListNode[]` with zero elements.